# how to use filter in polars

Tags: python, rust, python-polars, rust-polars

In polars-py, I can do this:

```
data.groupby('date').agg([
    pl.col("name").sort_by('factor').head(5).filter(pl.col("x")==1).alias('small'),
    pl.col("name").sort_by('factor').tail(5).filter(pl.col("x")==0).alias('big'),
    
]).sort('date')
```

But in polars-rs,how could I do the same filter thing?

```
data .lazy().groupby([col("date")]).agg(
    [ col("name").sort_by([col("factor")],[false]).alias("small")]
)
.sort("date", false)
.collect()
```

and where can I find some docs about Expr in rust? There are so few examples about polars-rs.

Comment: See [`Expr`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/polars/prelude/enum.Expr.html). I don't use this library myself, but based on your Python example, I'd assume you want `.filter(col("x").eq(1))` for example.

Comment: thank you, I have tried `.filter(col("x").eq(1))` ,but got an error `expected enum Expr, found integer`

Comment: ` .filter(col("x").eq(lit(1)))`